# Error al enviar correo desde heroku-laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email, heroku

Tengo un problema a la hora de enviar un email de confirmación de cuenta, lo pruebo en el localhost y funciona correcto, pero al desplegar la aplicación en heroku no envía el email, este es mi método register:

```
protected function register(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $validator = $this->validator($input);
    $tutor = Role::where('name','tutor')->first();

    if ($validator->passes()) {

        $data = $this->create($input)->toArray();
        $data['token'] = str_random(25);
        $user = User::find($data['id']);
        $user->token = $data['token'];
        $user->save();


            Mail::send('mails.confirmation', $data, function ($message) use($data){
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('Registration Confirmation');
        });
        return redirect(route('login'))->with('status', 'Se ha enviado el correo electrónico de confirmación. Por favor, revise su bandeja de entrada.');
    }
    return redirect(route('login'))->with('status', $validator->errors());
}
```

Al hacer el registro el guarda el nuevo usuario en la BD pero no envía el email de confirmación, solo muestra este error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 
Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 
t22sm5492950qke.49 - gsmtp"
```

Este es mi mail.php

```
return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),   
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'mi_email@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Discapp'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
];
```

Y estas las configuraciones en mi .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=discapp1991@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=dmxsxcrowuaadkco
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Agradecería cualquier recomendación, llevo varios dias sin poderlo hacer funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

@DVertel

Hace poco nos ocurrió y luego de intentar varias cosas, lo solucionamos provisionalmente activando el "Acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras" en la cuenta de GMail que se estaba utilizando para el envío.

> Para mantener protegidas las cuentas de los usuarios de G Suite, es posible que bloqueemos el acceso de apps menos seguras a las cuentas de G Suite. Si eres usuario de G Suite, verás el error "Contraseña incorrecta" cuando intentes acceder. Si este es el caso, tienes dos opciones:
>
> Opción 1: Actualizar a una app más segura que use las medidas de seguridad más recientes. Todos los productos de Google, como Gmail, usan medidas de seguridad actualizadas.
>
> **Opción 2: Cambiar la configuración para permitir que apps menos seguras accedan a la cuenta. No recomendamos esta opción, ya que podría facilitar el acceso de terceros a la cuenta. Si, de todos modos, quieres otorgar el acceso, sigue estos pasos:**
>
> **Ve a la sección Aplicaciones menos seguras en "Mi cuenta".
> Selecciona Activar junto a "Acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras". (Nota para los usuarios de G Suite: Esta opción de configuración estará oculta si el administrador bloqueó el acceso de apps menos seguras a la cuenta)**.

Referencia: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es-419